# Printing simple math

Tags: performance

My teacher told me that it is more efficient and faster to print a variable that is equal to the answer rather than print the answer itself. Is this true? Why?

```
int num1 = 5;
int num2 = 1;
int answer;

answer = num1 * num2;


System.out.println(num1 * num2);
System.out.println(answer);
```

Assuming the answer variable is never used again after this. I understand that the difference is negligible but I don't see the point of having a new variable just for the answer.

Answer (score 0):

In computer science,effiiceincy of a program is depended on two factors

- Time Complexity
- Space Complexity

If a similar operation is used many times in a program its better to store the result in a variable.( Assignment operation requires less time and space rahter than other operations).

If it occurs only once just use the operations

if you want to know in detailed about this concept search for design and analysis of algorithms